# Writing a string to panel with Forms Load Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi

I am trying to draw a string using `DrawString()` method on a panel(`panel1`). I want this to happen when the form(`Form1`) loads. But that doesn't happen. But the string is drawn, if I use the same code(given below) in the click event handler for `panel1`. Where am I doing it wrong?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /*string rand = getRandomString();
        textBox1.Text = rand;*/
        string rand = "Hello";
        SolidBrush sbr = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        FontFamily fam = new FontFamily("Magneto");
        Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(fam, 24, FontStyle.Bold);
        g.DrawString(rand, font, sbr, new Point(20, 20));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This event happens before the form is displayed. So after you draw the text on the panel, panel is repainted and your changes are lost.

Even the text drawn later during `Click` event will disappear if the form is repainted, so you need to handle Panel control's `Paint` event and do your drawing there.

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted only gets executed once - when the form has a redraw triggered (such as getting another form over it, etc) it will dissapear.  The same goes for your method in the button click event.

The way to draw onto the panel is as follows:

```
private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    var g = e.Graphics;
    /*string rand = getRandomString();
    textBox1.Text = rand;*/
    string rand = "Hello";
    using (var sbr = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
    { 
        FontFamily fam = new FontFamily("Magneto");
        Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(fam, 24, FontStyle.Bold);
        g.DrawString(rand, font, sbr, new Point(20, 20));
    }

}
```

The paint event for a control fires each time a redraw is required, so whatever you draw will not disappear unexpectedly.

Comment: Is there a way to invoke the Paint() event of the panel through a button-click? Like If I need a 'refresh' button to change the drawn string.

Comment: I did this using the panel1.Invalidate() method and it worked fine. Thanks still